# MySQL table incrementing by 10 for some reason

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

The id field in a mysql table is incrementing by 10 (11, 21, 31) for some reason.  Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I do a simple insert statement in SQL the next ID will be 41.

Answer (score 9):

You have [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) set to 10, change it back to 1.

Comment: +1 Would you know why it starts at 11 when AUTO_INCREMENT is set to 52?

Comment: My guess would be that you set the AUTO_INCREMENT after already inserting some values, but without your session logs I can't be sure.