# Auto Increment Issue - Incrementing By 10

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm getting a strange issue on my database.

**All auto increment fields of my database (all tables) are getting increment by 10.**

Previously it was working fine (increment by 1). And now its started to increment by 10.

Table 1

[image: table 1]

Another table

[image: table 2]

Comment: Can you show table schema ?

Comment: See:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993800/mysql-table-incrementing-by-10-for-some-reason and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) system variable to 1.

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Something like that :

`SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;`

or for specific table :

`ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT =1;`

Or you can refer [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may set the auto_increment_increment variable to 1

SET @@auto_increment_increment=1

SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;

in mysql it will work definitely.